# Rails how to use except with a list of ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Example I have some ids in my application controller:

```
@clicked = %w(32, 18, 13)
```

And in my controller I have:

```
@konkurrencer = Konkurrencer.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

How do I remove the Konkurrencer with the IDS 32, 18 and 13 from @konkurrencer?

And how to implement a clicked attribute (boolean) to konkurrencer. Example then it would be possible in the loop to do `<% if kon.clicked %>CLICKED<% end %>` it would be true if the kon had a id in the `@clicked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use NOT IN, I've tested without the paginate part, try and let me now if it works:

```
@konkurrencer = Konkurrencer.where("id NOT IN(?)", @clicked).order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Be sure the `@clicked` variable is an array as moo is too short suggests.

Comment: You don't need `@clicked.to_a.join(',')`, just `@clicked` will do; unless of course `@clicked` is empty, then you'd be better off with a scope like `def except(ids); ids.present?? where('id not in (?)', ids) : scoped;end`.

Comment: Yes I've edited the response just before you're comment to explain the reason to the to_a call, thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: I should have said `def self.except(ids)`, scopes with arguments are generally class methods. Using `to_a` to cast a `nil` to an Array is a good trick; AR will do the `join` (with proper quoting and escaping) on its own though :)

Comment: It works with pagination. I will accept your answer. Just gonna find out how to add create a model column "clicked" (boolean) for the Konkurrencer and find out how to add true if it is in the clicked array.

Comment: Add the column to the konkurrencers table should be trivial, just run $rails g migration AddClickedToKonkurrencers and modify accordingly the migration generated. I've not really clear what do you mean in the second part, I guess you would like to update one or more records' clicked attribute based on the @clicked array, it would be better ask another question for this ;)

Comment: @Railsbeginner: Are you using the `def self.except` version? Is it just a naming issue? Did you add it to the Konkurrencer class? Are you calling it as `Konkurrencer.except(@clicked).order(...).paginate(...)`?

Comment: I am calling it as you described last in your comment

Answer (score 0):

You could use [delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)

Comment: Bad idea. That would require an (possibly) expensive SQL query fetching results you might not need, and then traversing them all and removing them. You should keep this at the database level

Comment: Good point. I'll leave this here as reference as a working solution, but something to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As ghr mentioned, you could use delete_if but if you have a bunch of ids, the condition logic might get long.  As an alternative, but somewhat expensive solution, you could just "subtract" the target items by building another collection:

```
 @konkurrencer = Konkurrencer.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC') - Konkurrencer.find(32,18,13)
```

Comment: It would be really cool if the minus operator would be overridden so that difference between ActiveRecord::Relation object will cause the query to be rewritten as the other operations like order, limit, and so on :)